# Installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 desktop amd64 from Windows

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

Whats wrong with this version of installer?

No error, no warning and is not moving forward from here. My Internet connection is also good.

I really don't understand still how much time will it takes to download amd64.tar.xz

Please, can any one help me in installing Ubuntu?

Sorry, bit I am unable to provide screen shots as I'm not having a reputation of 10 :(

Comment: Are you trying to install using `wubi`. Did you restart windows or are you installing when windows is running?

Comment: Put a screen shot on any other file sharing website and send us a link buy going to [edit] on your post.

Answer (score 1):

I've supplied you with a couple of different links that may be, or may not be, of some assistance to you depending on where the problem lies.

### Installers

If the problem lies with the installation process itself, please refer to the following links and let us know which one it is that you are having issues:

Are you attempting to use the Windows installer [wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)? (See link)
Are you following these instructions on creating a [bootable USB-stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)?

### Download Speed

If the download speed is causing you problems, you might try a different download:
If you are attempting to download Ubuntu from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
try the following sources [Alternative Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads), or vice versa.

Perhaps I missed the mark, and your problem lies elsewhere entirely.
Try editing your question to provide a more elaborate and cohesive view of
what the problem seems to be and we'll be more likely to provide the help that
you need.